# Twitter Timestamps - Can they be overriden?

Tags: json, twitter, timestamp

I'm sure the account @FifNdhs has popped in your time line,  their tweets accurately "predicting" the outcome of the world cup final became viral after the game ended.

Most claim that the account wrote up every possible outcome, and deleted the wrong ones after the match. Seeing the level of detail the tweets were, it seems quite tedious.

So, my question is, could it have been done pragmatically? I know the documentation for the twitter API doesn't show the possibility of specifying a timestamp (See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update) but don't you think there is a way around it?

Comment: What basis do you have for thinking that there is a "way around" this? Anyway, this isn't a question about programming.

Comment: No basis, just my oblivion to the underworkings of a web-api and the tendency for one to keep their system's holes hidden. If there's a program that can do it, it is a programming question

Comment: No, just because a program may exist to do something does not make that something on-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, [there are only a few possible outcomes of a football match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals) - ignoring outliers like Germany's 7-1 defeat of Brazil.

So, you need a program which will spit out (pseudo code):

```
for $x = 0 to 5
    print "Team A $x - "
    for $y = 0 to 5
        print "$y - Team B"
```

As for the goal scorers, all you need is a list of all the players and to iterate through it saying `$player will score`.

So, yes, it is possible to do this in a non-tedious fashion.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, upon further inspection of the tweets, the ones without attribution to the number of goals and the player, appear to be general and do not conform to specific outcome or the other "There will be a goal in ET"